# Cant return an element in react-native

Tags: react-native

In my new react native app, I can't write the following code.

```
  renderContent = () => {
    let content = null;

    content = <View><Text>HI</Text></View>;
    return content;
 }
```

I use this inside the render() like this.

```
render() {
  {this.renderContent}
}
```

It gives me the following error.
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

my RN version is 59. I used this pattern successfully in version 54. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: should do `render(){ return this.renderContent() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow this format:

```
render(){ 
    return this.renderContent() 
}
```

`{something}` is for `jsx`. For example for this:

```
return(
    <View>{something}</View>
)
```